# CTRL+F doesn't work in chrome browser when embeding pdf in html

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I used embed tag to view pdf docs in html but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for some word  doesn't work in pdf embeded under chrome browser. (I don't want to change the browser).

```
<embed src="pathToDocs/docs/mydoc.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="80%" height="80%" />
```

Is there any way to activate this option (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)? I need it in my application.

Comment: Fixed in Chrome 60: https://crbug.com/55421

Answer (score 0):

Atleast post the code which is causing problem. Use a utility such as [pdfObject](https://pdfobject.com/) to embed the Pdf document.

**EDIT - Working**

You can use google's PDF viewer like this - :

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:1400px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Whenever you click on the document and press ctrl + f or f3 it will pop up the viewer's search feature which will highlight the words. Just replace the url of the file to your filename in the code above.

If you don't want to use this your other option is to custom build the search functionality using javascript which will highlight all the words matching the pattern and override the chrome's default ctrl + f feature.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to insert the code but it is simple :               < embed src="pathToDocs/docs/mydoc.pdf"  type="application/pdf"  width="80%" height="80%"  />.  Its the same for iframe and object tags.

Comment: i tried pdfobject utility but it doesn't even show my pdf doc. please help

Comment: any help please

Comment: thanks for reply..  my application is not connected to the internet, so I can't use docs.google viewer. For the other option, my question is how to custom the browser search functionality. thanks